# Shape of snowflakes

Tags: reference-request, crystals, mp.mathematical-physics

Is there a mathematical theory that explains the shape of a snowflake? Why is it not round?

**Update** Tree-like metric spaces appear often as limits of sequences of metric spaces (say, [asymptotic cones](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405030) or  [boundaries](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgak/abstracts/qid.html) of metric spaces). I wonder if similar objects can be obtained as shapes minimizing some kind of energy functional. This may lead to new constructions in geometric group theory.

I just saw Igor Rivin's answer which may be what is needed. Perhaps somebody can give a more detailed answer?

Comment: Water crystallizes in a hexagonal lattice, so small snowflakes are just hexagons.  For reasons of surface chemistry that I don't really understand, water molecules are more likely to attach at a vertex than in the middle of an edge, so as the hexagons get large the vertices grow faster than the edges, creating a non-convex figure with 12 edges.  Iterating this procedure (growing faster at vertices than at edges) gives a snowflake--for a picture of this, see pg. 884 here:  http://www.its.caltech.edu/~atomic/publist/rpp5_4_R03.pdf (the whole article is pretty interesting.  So really, the Koch...

Comment: ...snowflake with appropriately chosen parameters is not a bad model at all.

Comment: @Daniel: This may not be what I want since I wanted an explanation, not a description. An example of an explanation could be something like this: "consider the following `energy' functional ..., the shapes that minimize that functional are snowflakes."

Comment: The review that Daniel Litt linked to explains that the shapes of snowflakes are the outcome of a complicated _growth_ process, involving the competition of between the _rates_ of diffusion and attachment of water molecules and heat transport, among other things. In particular, as snowflakes are formed very far from the equilibrium state of water and ice, their overall shapes won't be the minimizers of any natural thermodynamic energy functional, or even randomly perturbed versions of such, in the way that large facets of crystals might be.

Comment: I think their shapes are more akin to the random fractals arising from diffusion-limited aggregation, where molecules diffusing in "from infinity" attach to a seed.  I think this paper http://psoup.math.wisc.edu/papers/h2l.pdf by the group that created the pictures that Joseph O'Rourke linked to below is probably the best current explanation for snowflakes, and has a similar philosophy starting from _growth_ rather than _minimization_ - create a random growth model (on a lattice, even) with certain physically motivated properties and one finds shapes that match well the real life snowflakes.

Comment: @jc: Thank you! This is also how limits of spaces "grow" into fractals. But the chemical reason from Daniel's comment should be a minimizer reason? Thus the reason why the molecules are glued the way they are glued should be "because it minimizes some energy functional". Right? I do not think the article you mention gives any reason for this except that "the experiments show that". Perhaps I missed something, I am not very good at reading chemistry/physics papers. 

Comment: I looked at the papers suggested by Igor Rivin. I think it is indeed close to what I wanted. Also his answer was first, so I have accepted it. 

Comment: See also this MSE question: [Horizontal drift of snowflake](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/623409/237).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is a quite active theory of crystal formation, in which the late Fred Almgren and the very much with us Jean Taylor did groundbreaking work. If you google "ALmgren Taylor dendrites" you will be enlightened. You can read the papers (and papers referring to the papers) -- I think the theory is not so simple.

Answer (score 18):

Janko Gravner at UC Davis and David Griffeath at the University of Wisconsin-Madison
have modeled snowflake growth, as reported on [this web page](http://www.physorg.com/news119784799.html):

> the researchers were able to recreate a wide range of natural snowflake shapes.
>   Rather than trying to model every water molecule, it divides the space into three-dimensional chunks one micrometer across. The program takes about 24 hours to produce one "snowfake" on a modern desktop computer.

[image: Snowflake]
Paper, code, and movies on this modeling are available [here](http://psoup.math.wisc.edu/Snowfakes.htm).
Here is a [1min17sec YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEWYVCbOskQ) of growth simulations following this model;
and here is a [26sec, more colorful set of simulations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_a2oTC1Ekk&feature=endscreen&NR=1).

---

**Added**. Some added detail from the G-G papers:

> The building blocks for snowflakes are hexagonally arranged molecules of natural ice (*Ih*). Just how the elaborate designs emerge as water vapor freezes is still poorly understood....
>   The solidification process involves complex physical chemistry of diffusion limited aggregation and attachment kinetics....Our basic set-up features solidification Cellular Automata on the triangular lattice $\mathbb{T}$ (to reflect the arrangement of water molecules in ice crystals).

To echo Igor, it's "not so simple"!

---

A more physically based, 3D model is explored in the paper
"Monte Carlo Simulation of the Formation of Snowflakes," by Maruyman and Fujiyoshi
[Journal of the Atmospheric Sciences](http://journals.ametsoc.org/toc/atsc/62/5), 2005.
Comparisons of the shape to "observed snowflakes" are made:

               
[image: Snowflake Observed]

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks! But right now I see lots of snowflakes appearing in real time outside my window.:) 

Answer (score 12):

I was curious about the OP's second question, which I now think is actually rather difficult.  Namely

> Why is it [the shape of a snowflake] not round?

Various physics-y sources (e.g. [this paper](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~atomic/publist/rpp5_4_R03.pdf)) suggest the following "explanation" for the shape of a snowflake, which I mention in my comment on the original question--namely, that water crystallizes in a hexagonal lattice, so small snowflakes are just hexagons; new water molecules are more likely to attach at corners than edges or faces (for complicated reasons I don't really understand) so vertices grow faster than edges.  Thus the hexagon will become a non-convex 6-pointed star; then the edges of this figure will split similarly, and so on.  This interpretation is born out by e.g. the picture on pg. 884 of the paper above.

This inspired the following simple model, which comes in both deterministic and random flavors.  We'll build a snowflake on the standard hexagonal lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$, spanned by e.g. $(1, 0)$ and $(1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$.  Start with a single regular hexagon of side length $1$ centered at the origin, with vertices the six shortest lattice vectors.

In the deterministic version of the model, at each positive integer time $t$ we add a regular lattice hexagon with side length $1$ centered at each lattice point which is the vertex of exactly one hexagon.  In the random version, at each positive integer time $t$, we add a hexagon centered at a random lattice point which is the vertex of exactly one hexagon with uniform probability over such lattice points.

I had some time this morning, so I coded up both models in the language "Processing."  Here is a typical pair of snowflakes from the deterministic model:

[image]

[image]

This model has the following interesting properties, none of which are particularly difficult to prove.

> 1) By the envelope of a snowflake I mean the smallest simply-connected polygon containing it.  Let $S_n$ be the envelope of the snowflake at time $n$.  Consider the sequence $S_n$ in the space of plane polygons metrized by Hausdorff distance, modulo homothety (two polygons are homothetic if one is congruent to a rescaling of the other).  Then $S_n$ is recurrent (that is, any homothety class visited by $S_n$ is approached arbitrarily closely infinitely many times).  However, the only homothety class taken infinitely many times by the $S_n$ is that of a regular hexagon.  (Thus in this setting the adage that no two snowflakes are alike is pretty far off.)
>
> 2)  Let $H_n$ be the smallest regular hexagon containing $S_n$.  Then $$\frac{\text{area}(S_n)}{\text{area}(H_n)}$$ is bounded above by $1$ and below by, say $1/2$ (though one can do better).  By virtue of the recurrence of the $S_n$, however, this ratio does not attain a limit.
>
> 3)  Certain interior triangles are never filled in, and as is visible in the pictures above these follow a beautiful regular pattern which I haven't bothered to work out.

Now let's look at the random model.  Here are two typical snowflakes:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, these are quite round, so they might be better called snowballs.  I understand this model much less well than the deterministic one above.  However, the following conjectures are natural given the pictures.

> 4) (Conjecture) In the space of homothety classes of plane polygons, metrized by Hausdorff distance, as in (1) above, the envelopes of these shapes tend towards the homothety class of a circle with probability $1$.
>
> 5) (Conjecture) The ratio $$\frac{\text{perimiter}(S_n)}{\sqrt{\text{area}(S_n)}}$$ tends to infinity with probability $1$.

In other words--the random model I implicitly suggested in my comment on the original question seems to give round snowflakes!  So I at least think the physics question as to why snowflakes aren't round is still pretty interesting.

---

In the comments, Rebecca Bellovin suggests another random model--namely, fix a probability $0\leq p\leq 1$ and at each time $t$, and each valid lattice point (namely, each lattice point which is the vertex of exactly one hexagon) add a hexagon centered at that point with probability $p$.  At least for small $t$ (e.g. $t<10000$), this seems to interpolate between the two models I give here, and certainly if one scales $p$ in proportion to the number of valid lattice points (so that for example the probability is negligible that more than one hexagon will be added, or that no valid points will be missed), these models will behave exactly like the ones I give.  On the other hand, for middling $p$, something interesting happens--namely, the snowflakes look like rounded hexagons.  At Rebecca's request, I am posting a picture for $p=0.7$, below:

[image]

I have no real explanation for this phenomenon; only unconvincing heuristics.

Comment: I'd be happy to send the Processing code/java applet to anyone who'd like to play with these models--my email is in my MO profile.

Comment: I don't like your random model: it seems much more reasonable to fix a probability p and at time t, attach a new hexagon at every available lattice point with probability p.  Assuming a fair amount of water in the air, water crystallizing at one vertex should be independent of water crystallizing at other vertices (to a first approximation).

Comment: This is really just the same as assuming no two molecules attach at exactly the same time, which happens with probability $1$ anyway in any continuous model...

Comment: @Rebecca:  In fact, I just coded up your suggestion--unsurprisingly, it seems to interpolate between the two models here (very similar to the first if $p$ is large, and similar to the second if $p$ is small).

Comment: It's not the same as assuming no molecules attach at the same time, because in your random model you're effectively adjusting the probability of attachment based on the size of the snowflake.  If anything, you want to adjust the probabilities based on the geometry --- I would guess that available vertices deep "inside" the snowflake would have lower probabilities of attachment.

Comment: I think I can show that your objection doesn't effect the "shape" properties I'm discussing here (e.g. in points 1-5), only the growth rate.  But if you have some "shape" property in mind that you can show differs in the model you suggest, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: (And indeed, my simulations suggest the shape properties are essentially the same as the ones given here for $p$ close to $0$ or $1$.)

Comment: Nice! Is it similar to percolation clusters, self-avoiding random walks, etc.?

Comment: @Mark:  I have no idea, unfortunately; I don't know much about either subject.

Comment: @Daniel: I know some people who know these subjects. I will ask when I see them.

Comment: The random model looks very close to the Richardson growth process; my web page shows 3D images http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~bkloeckn/images.html and Olivier Garet's one has many images of related random processes http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~garet/images.php

Comment: Your random models don't quite capture the character of the processes that make snowflakes spiky because in diffusion-limited aggregation type models (those related to snowflake growth), the growth rate at boundary sites is not uniform, but rather is the harmonic measure from infinity, which is more heavily weighted on "spiky" regions of the boundary.

Comment: Are there some news/explanations for the "hexagonal"model you tried here?

Comment: @Olga:  I haven't thought about this in many years -- it's rather far outside my wheelhouse.  If you have any specific questions, I can try to dig up the old code, though...

Answer (score 0):

Recently the Veritasium published a video on YouTube about [The Snowflake Mystery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao2Jfm35XeE); the video follows the work of Dr Ken Libbrecht which spend a bulk of his life studying snowflakes. Here is one of his recent papers:

[A Quantitative Physical Model of the Snow Crystal Morphology Diagram](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1910/1910.09067.pdf)

It is obviously not the full answer to the OP question, but it looks like snowflake must know.